# Peaking Equalizer

Tags: discrete-signals

I'm making peaking equalizer in C# using NAudio ([EQ-Cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt)). Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code? It gives me noise.

[Sliders](http://shrani.si/f/2o/Qz/3bOWbf1i/eq.png)

```
    class Equalizer : WaveStream
{
    float[] sFc;
    double a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;
    public Equalizer(WaveStream source)
    {
        sourceStream = source;
        sFc = new float[] { 50, 80, 130, 350, 1300, 4000, 8000, 12000, 16000 };
    }
    public WaveStream sourceStream
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Length; }
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            sourceStream.Position = value;
        }
    }
    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return sourceStream.WaveFormat; }
    }

    //x - input buffer, y - output buffer, Fc - center frequency , dbGain - gain in db
    public void PeakingEQ(float[] x,ref float[] y, float Fc, float dbGain)
    {
        //q=2, ~octave bandwith
        double w0 = 2 * Math.PI * Fc / sourceStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        double cosw0 = Math.Cos(w0);
        double sinw0 = Math.Sin(w0);
        double alpha = sinw0 / 4; //sin(w0)/(2*Q) ->q=2    
        double A = Math.Pow(10, dbGain / 40);
        b0 = 1 + alpha * A;
        b1 = -2 * cosw0;
        b2 = 1 - alpha * A;
        a0 = 1 + alpha / A;
        a1 = -2 * cosw0;
        a2 = 1 - alpha / A;
        for (int n = 2; n < x.Length; n++)
        {
            y[n] += (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * x[n - 1] + (b2 / a0) * x[n - 2] - (a1 / a0) * y[n - 1] - (a2 / a0) * y[n - 2]);
            y[n] = Math.Min(1, Math.Max(-1, y[n]));
        }
   }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        float[] f_read = new float[read / 4], y = new float[read / 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, f_read, 0, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < Form1.trackBarValue.Length; i++)
            PeakingEQ(f_read, ref y, sFc[i], Form1.trackBarValue[i]);

        Buffer.BlockCopy(y, 0, buffer, offset, read);
        return read;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is edited code: caching last two input and output samples

```
    class Equalizer : WaveStream
{
    float[] cacheInput, cacheOutput;
    float[] sFc;
    double a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;
    public Equalizer(WaveStream source)
    {
        sourceStream = source;
        sFc = new float[] { 50, 80, 130, 350, 1300, 4000, 8000, 12000, 16000 };
        cacheInput = new float[2];
        cacheOutput = new float[2];
    }
    public WaveStream sourceStream
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Length; }
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            sourceStream.Position = value;
        }
    }
    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return sourceStream.WaveFormat; }
    }

    //x - input buffer, y - output buffer, Fc - center frequency , dbGain - gain in db
    public void PeakingEQ(float[] x,ref float[] y, float Fc, float dbGain)
    {
        //q=2, ~octave bandwith
        double w0 = 2 * Math.PI * Fc / sourceStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        double cosw0 = Math.Cos(w0);
        double sinw0 = Math.Sin(w0);
        double alpha = sinw0 / 4; //sin(w0)/(2*Q) ->q=2    
        double A = Math.Pow(10, dbGain / 40);
        b0 = 1 + alpha * A;
        b1 = -2 * cosw0;
        b2 = 1 - alpha * A;
        a0 = 1 + alpha / A;
        a1 = -2 * cosw0;
        a2 = 1 - alpha / A;
        for (int n = 0; n < x.Length; n++)
        {
            if (n ==0)
            {
                y[n] += (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * cacheInput[0] + (b2 / a0) * cacheInput[1] - (a1 / a0) * cacheOutput[0] - (a2 / a0) * cacheOutput[1]);
            }
            else if (n == 1)
            {
                y[n] += (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * x[n - 1] + (b2 / a0) * cacheInput[0] - (a1 / a0) * y[n - 1] - (a2 / a0) * cacheOutput[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                y[n] += (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * x[n - 1] + (b2 / a0) * x[n - 2] - (a1 / a0) * y[n - 1] - (a2 / a0) * y[n - 2]);
            }
            y[n] = Math.Min(1, Math.Max(-1, y[n]));
        }
   }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        float[] f_read = new float[read / 4], y = new float[read / 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, f_read, 0, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < Form1.trackBarValue.Length; i++)
            PeakingEQ(f_read, ref y, sFc[i], Form1.trackBarValue[i]);

        //caching last two input samples
        cacheInput[0] = f_read[f_read.Length - 1];
        cacheInput[1] = f_read[f_read.Length - 2];

        //caching last two output samples
        cacheOutput[0] = y[y.Length - 1];
        cacheOutput[1] = y[y.Length - 2];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(y, 0, buffer, offset, read);
        return read;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** caching output for each filter

```
    class Equalizer : WaveStream
{
    float[] cacheInput;
    float [, ] cacheOutput;
    float[] sFc;
    double a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;
    public Equalizer(WaveStream source)
    {
        sourceStream = source;
        sFc = new float[] { 50, 80, 130, 350, 1300, 4000, 8000, 12000, 16000 };
        cacheInput = new float[2];
        cacheOutput = new float[sFc.Length,2];
    }
    public WaveStream sourceStream
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Length; }
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            sourceStream.Position = value;
        }
    }
    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return sourceStream.WaveFormat; }
    }

    //x - input buffer, y - output buffer, Fc - center frequency , dbGain - gain in db
    public void PeakingEQ(float[] x,ref float[] y, float Fc, float dbGain, int index)
    {
        //q=2, ~octave bandwith
        double w0 = 2 * Math.PI * Fc / sourceStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        double cosw0 = Math.Cos(w0);
        double sinw0 = Math.Sin(w0);
        double alpha = sinw0 / 4; //sin(w0)/(2*Q) ->q=2    
        double A = Math.Pow(10, dbGain / 40);
        b0 = 1 + alpha * A;
        b1 = -2 * cosw0;
        b2 = 1 - alpha * A;
        a0 = 1 + alpha / A;
        a1 = -2 * cosw0;
        a2 = 1 - alpha / A;
        float tmp=0;
        for (int n = 0; n < x.Length; n++)
        {
            if (n ==0)
                tmp= (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * cacheInput[0] + (b2 / a0) * cacheInput[1] - (a1 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 0] - (a2 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 1]);
            else if (n == 1)
                tmp = (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * x[n - 1] + (b2 / a0) * cacheInput[0] - (a1 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 0] - (a2 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 1]);
            else
                tmp = (float)((b0 / a0) * x[n] + (b1 / a0) * x[n - 1] + (b2 / a0) * x[n - 2] - (a1 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 0] - (a2 / a0) * cacheOutput[index, 1]);

            y[n] += tmp;
            cacheOutput[index, 1] = cacheOutput[index, 0];
            cacheOutput[index, 0] = tmp;
        }
   }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        float[] f_read = new float[read / 4], y = new float[read / 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, f_read, 0, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < Form1.trackBarValue.Length; i++)
            PeakingEQ(f_read, ref y, sFc[i], Form1.trackBarValue[i],i);

        for (int n = 0; n < read / 4; n++)
            y[n] = Math.Min(1, Math.Max(-1, y[n] / sFc.Length));

        cacheInput[0] = f_read[f_read.Length - 1];
        cacheInput[1] = f_read[f_read.Length - 2];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(y, 0, buffer, offset, read);
        return read;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a recording of the output? Can you describe what kind of "noise" you hear?

To start with, you do not fill the first two samples `y[0]` and `y[1]` ; and the state variables `x[n-1]`, `x[n-2]`, `y[n-1]`, `y[n-2]` are reset every time `PeakingEQ` is called. This will cause a glitch at each buffer boundary, which can be quite often if `Read` is called on small chunks. Your class needs to store somewhere the last two input samples and last two output samples to ensure continuous rendering.

Comment: No sorry, I don't have a recording of the output. The SNR ratio is very poor.. however if I also store input buffer into y[] before calling function PeakingEQ then the signal is a little better, but the noise is still there. Thanks for the answer, I have edited the code, but the noise is still there.

Comment: The noise is kinda following the signal: if there are low tones, then the noise gets lower and the opposite for high tones.

Comment: @user755974: What kind of noise?  Hissing?  Buzzing?

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into more details about it - this is a programming question more than a DSP question and as such is off-topic here - but it looks like you want to sum the output of several filters to implement your EQ. To do so:

- In the filter equations, $y_{n-1}$ and $y_{n-2}$ refer to the past samples output by the filter. For example, when you render the 1300 Hz filter, `y[n-1]` and `y[n-2]` must refer to the previous samples produced by the 1300 Hz filter. In your code, these variables are storing the sum of the output of all filters. You are not accessing the past of the filter but the past of your sum of 9 filters - and this is one of the reasons why it crashes.
- You need to preserve the state variable of each filter, not just global state variable (which is meaningless). There are 9 filters, so you'll need to store 9 sets of past output coefficients.

So don't try to be too smart and do too many things at once. Write a `PeakingEQ` function that works in a fresh buffer (`y[n] = ...`) and keeps track of its own state variable. Get it to work. Then call it several times and accumulate the results in your output buffer. You can clip at the very last step. Then optimize...

Once you got this fixed, keep in mind also that you'll be summing the output of 9 filters - there's probably a `/9` you'll have to add somewhere to keep the global gain unitary when the EQ is set to a flat response.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the code. I don't really understand why should I keep track of all filter coefficients and not using global state variable. The coefficients are recalculated every time when PeakingEQ is called (PeakingEQ function also take center frequency as a parameter). Now I'm getting the signal without a noise, but it seems to me that filters are not really affecting the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of answering "what's wrong with my code" I will try to answer the probably more useful "What can I do to figure out what's wrong".
There are few things that are useful in debugging these type of problems:

1. Check your coefficients against a reference for "known good" filter. For example 1 kHz, 6dB gain, Q =2 and sample rate 44.1 kHz should result in normalized coefficients of b = [1.0341   -1.9119    0.897] and a = [1.0000   -1.9119    0.9314]
2. Try some simple signals where you know the answer. Try the 1kHz/+6dB filter wsith a 40 Hz sine wave. You should get input = output (or very close to that). Then try a 1 kHz sine wave. The output should be roughly twice the size of the input
3. You can also inspect the output sine wave for any discontinuities are shape deformation
4. Replace the filtering with a very simple operation. For example output = input*0.1. IF that doesn't work, then your problem has nothing to do with the filtering but with routing inputs and outputs.

Two more remarks

1. Your code is very inefficiently written. Unless you have a really good optimizing compiler this may take a lot more CPU cycles that it has to (which may or may not be a problem)
2. You hard clip the min and max of the output to [-1,+1]. That would be probably be unacceptable for any commercial application. For a hobby project that's okay.